# Deserializing nullable TimeSpan Property throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Getting Argumentnull exception when I tried to deserialize a nullable TimeSpan property.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    private TimeSpan? m_WorkStartHr;

    public TimeSpan? WorkStartHr
    {
        get { return m_WorkStartHr; }
        set { m_WorkStartHr = value; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        TimeSpan? dt = new TimeSpan(288000000000);
        SimpleClass instance = new SimpleClass();
        instance.WorkStartHr = dt;

        string jsonStr = serializer.Serialize(instance);

        //This code throws the exception
        SimpleClass newInstance = serializer.Deserialize<SimpleClass>(jsonStr);
    }
}
```

Note: If we make WorkStartHr non nullable, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a known issue with the JavaScriptSerializer.

[There's a workaround here](http://juristr.com/blog/2012/02/aspnet-mvc3-doesnt-deserialize-nullable/), but it isn't ideal.

Comment: thanks. Will try that. One more workaround I found was to use https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/336. This worked in my case. Is Microsoft coming up with any solution for this? I don't want to use any work around.

Comment: It seems Microsoft has largely abandoned the JavaScriptSerializer. The Web API for example uses JSON.NET, and Microsoft contributes to that project now. I'd recommend you check out that serialization library instead.